# button_to confirmation not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I cannot get the delete to do the are you sure confirmation.

```
<td><%= button_to 'Delete',  { action: "destroy", id: profile.id},
    method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} %>
</td>
```

when I do inspect element I get:

```
<input name="_method" value="delete" type="hidden">
<input data-confirm="Are you sure?" value="Delete" type="submit">
<input name="authenticity_token" value="tlKQbZ0mI6aQ/pmuAtVdugbMzABI12oRpLoP5UDLmUNGWhzaIi2vYihIXfmUXpo6ruqqLKiCZQcmFOVQQF2n1A==" type="hidden">
```

here is `application.js`

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery2
//= require jquery-ujs
//= require_tree .
```

here is the gem
gem `jquery-rails`

Comment: <form class="button_to" method="post" action="/profiles/46"><input name="_method" value="delete" type="hidden"><input data-confirm="Are you sure?" value="Delete" type="submit"><input name="authenticity_token" value="Vjb9I9iwuK4tLDnLO/c0Rd3bCtWMWV3MapBvJhA4ENASm5t/Afs2G1FITvrOU7zoed/b2kwm2j8wIdg5YqVSgQ==" type="hidden"></form>  is what i get for inspect element

Comment: <td><%= button_to 'Delete', profile_path(id: profile.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure' } %>  yields <form class="button_to" method="post" action="/profiles/48"><input name="_method" value="delete" type="hidden"><input data-confirm="Are you sure" value="Delete" type="submit"><input name="authenticity_token" value="xNRN7qNqx1oKAq8eXrnb4cCH4N+UBnSzUa892UxS1Y6ClGGvEnwUKO+CAM+YP3x3qslPx38mniy1ZGkLYKRGAQ==" type="hidden"></form> same problem

Comment: Source map error: TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
Resource URL: moz-extension://99839d5f-3cf7-4b8b-aa10-c2dc14d50c7d/libs/lodash.min.js
Source Map URL: lodash.min.js.map[Learn More] i get this in the console tab of the firefox debugger not sure if relevant

Comment: If you want to add code to the question, please [edit] your question to include that code, instead of dumping it in comments. Code in comments is virtually unreadable; code in questions is not.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed via the jquery-rails gem, then I believe

```
//= require jquery-ujs
```

should be

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Try that first.